# Error filling database: field "price" is not "Android Studio version: 3.4.2"

Tags: android

I try to create a database and try to fill it, but the error that the field "price" is not, the code I showed and the state of the constant Util.KEY_PRICE that not so, for aid boloe thank you.The first time I am working with a database in Android Studio are doing in the classroom, in the video, but no way.Android Studio version: 3.4.2

try added this

```
SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHandler.getWritableDatabase(); in
MainActivity.java in onCreate ,don't work

    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, Util.DATABASE_NAME, null, Util.DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //SQL - structured query language (язык структурированных запросов)
            String CREATE_CARS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+Util.TABLE_NAME+"("
                    + Util.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + Util.KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + Util.KEY_PRICE + " TEXT" + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CARS_TABLE);

            //public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
        }
```

MainActivity.java :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

import Data.DatabaseHandler;
import Model.Car;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        //SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        databaseHandler.addCar(new Car("Toyota","30 000 $"));
        databaseHandler.addCar(new Car("Opel","25 000 $"));
        databaseHandler.addCar(new Car("Mersedes","50 000 $"));
        databaseHandler.addCar(new Car("KIA","28 000 $"));
        databaseHandler.addCar(new Car("Mazda","30 000 $"));
        databaseHandler.addCar(new Car("Honda","25 000 $"));
        databaseHandler.addCar(new Car("Skoda","50 000 $"));
        databaseHandler.addCar(new Car("Hundai","28 000 $"));
        List<Car> carList = databaseHandler.getAllCars();
        for (Car car : carList){
            Log.d("CarInfo : ","ID " + car.getId()+ ", name " + car.getName()+
                    ",price " + car.getPrice());
        }

    }
}


10-02 13:31:44.731 6356-6356/com.kozlov_v_s_2019.carsdb E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=Toyota price=30 000 $
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table cars has no column named price (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO cars(name,price) VALUES (?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at Data.DatabaseHandler.addCar(DatabaseHandler.java:43)
        at com.kozlov_v_s_2019.carsdb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: I suggest you to try "Room" for interacting with database in Android. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

Comment: problem is in `addCar` method. Show it.

Comment: also try uninstalling the app first. Probably the database was already created when you added the `price` field

Comment: show your addCar method and Util class